# Database select all data with table qualifier in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I need to select from a database some tables with many columns. So I want to select

```
select t1.*,t2.*,t3.*
from table1 t1 
left outer join table2 t2 on ...
left outer join tabl 3 t3 on ...
...
```

Some keys are identically named, but - due to the outer command - sometimes `null`. Unfortunately I cannot directly see whether the key comes from t1, t2 or t3. Is there any chance to add automatically the tablenames or another separating/distinguishing qualifier to all column names, i.e. `t1_thekey, t2_thekey, t3_thekey` ...?

Comment: Not automatically.  You need to rename each column one at a time.

Comment: To add to the above, many consider `SELECT *` to be undesirable, because its meaning changes as the number of columns in the table may change.  By explicitly listing out each column, you avoid this problem.

Comment: It becomes more tricky as I use it inside node-red. Since I get a JSON back, each key (= column name) is allowed only once. This results in overwriting existing values with null by the missing data set from one of the left outer tables. As there is no solution I definitely have to rename the columns manually.

Answer (score 2):

Postgres doesn't allow you to rename the columns *en masse*.  However, you could select the columns as records, so you can see where they come from:

```
select t1, t2, t3
```

Comment: Ok, interesting workaround. Thank you. ... But the column names are than missing?!

Comment: @MichaelHecht . . . You have a record name and then you have a field name within the records.